# Shared folders on Ubuntu 16.04 with VM Workstation 10.0 on Win 7

Tags: vmware, shared-folders

The really annoying thing here is that I had this working, but reinstalled my Host OS and lost my Suspended state for the VM - on rebooting, the shares have gone.

I've spent all day trying to resolve this with no joy.

I currently have ONE of my two shares showing in mnt/hgfs but with no files visible inside. The security settings on both host folders are identical, they are both shared and access granted to Everybody.

I installed vmware tools using the guide from here: https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches

Running vmware-hgfsclient lists the two shares ok

I cannot mount either share using 
sudo mount -t vmhgfs .host:/Music /mnt/hgfs
I get the error - cannot mount filesystem: No such device

I've rerun vmware-config-tools.pl - no change

I've run out of things to try now - I'm pretty sure last time I found a way to mount the folder at the command prompt, and although I was unable to apply the same in /etc/fstab, as long as I only suspended the machine, I never had to remount.

Answer (score 6):

You can mount them with

```
sudo /usr/bin/vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs -o subtype=vmhgfs-fuse,allow_other
```

see https://github.com/vmware/open-vm-tools/issues/199#issuecomment-335525133